# How do I clip an entity or geometry against underside of terrain

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am using the Cesium.Globe clipping planes to extract a square geographic section. But one problem is that terrain back-faces are not rendered which makes it look weird when the user selects a shallow viewing angle.

[image: Shallow View]

I thought one way to hide this was to render the "soil" as a box or wall under the terrain, but I would need the top of the box or wall to confirm to the terrain geometry (red line). 
I figure I can achieve this by using a [WallGeometry](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/WallGeometry.html) around the culled terrain instead of a box, and set the height of each section based on the result of a [sampleTerrain](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/sampleTerrain.html) call.

But I was wondering if Cesium doesn't provide an easier and cleaner way to do this. (Like perhaps some Boolean union function or something)

[image: Cut out box]

[Cesium Sandcastle link](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html#c=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)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
        skyAtmosphere: false,
        shouldAnimate : true,
        terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain()
    });
var globe = viewer.scene.globe;

var position = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(new Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(-113.2665534, 36.0939345, 100));
var distance = 3000.0;

globe.clippingPlanes = new Cesium.ClippingPlaneCollection({
    modelMatrix : Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(position),
    planes : [
        new Cesium.ClippingPlane(new Cesium.Cartesian3( 1.0,  0.0, 0.0), distance),
        new Cesium.ClippingPlane(new Cesium.Cartesian3(-1.0,  0.0, 0.0), distance),
        new Cesium.ClippingPlane(new Cesium.Cartesian3( 0.0,  1.0, 0.0), distance),
        new Cesium.ClippingPlane(new Cesium.Cartesian3( 0.0, -1.0, 0.0), distance)
    ],
    unionClippingRegions : true,
            edgeWidth:3,
    edgeColor: Cesium.Color.RED,
    enabled : true
});
var rockBox = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'RockBox',
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-113.2665534, 36.0939345, 900),
    box : {
        dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian3(distance*2, distance*2,800.0),
        material : Cesium.Color.GRAY.withAlpha(0.4),
        outline : true,
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.GRAY
    }
});
var waterTable = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'WaterTable',
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-113.2665534, 36.0939345, 440),
    box : {
        dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian3(distance*2, distance*2, 160.0),
        material : Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.9),
        outline : true,
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLUE
    }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to do this with the public API, but this does look like a good use case. This isn't documented but you can set a custom renderstate for most objects. For terrain you'd have to modify this source to set cull to disabled here:

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/Source/Scene/GlobeSurfaceTileProvider.js#L436-L458

And this is what it looks like:

https://imgur.com/aWIo86B

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to open a pull request to maybe just add a boolean property on terrain to set this, since I think that's vastly easier than constructing all this extra geometry just to hide it.

Comment: @OmarShehata, thank you that looks really good and for most use cases it would be enough I think. I'm going to have to give this some thought, as I suspect that at a later point I will have to visualize the "soil walls" anyway for soil layer concentrations of various substances.   The Ideal solution for me would be if I could use the terrain as a clipping plane against subsurface geometries.

Comment: I opened an issue for this, feel free to chime in there with anything I missed https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/7266

Terrain as clipping plane sounds like an interesting use case. I'm not sure how hard that'd be or if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At updated *CesiumGS* version (currently 1.72), we show back faces of terrain via public API like this:

```
viewer.scene.globe.backFaceCulling = false;
```